# Quarkus Kafka concurrency

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I use quarkus to process incoming messages from Kafka topic that has 4 partitions. While I ingest multiple messages to this topic I see the quarkus-kafka-consumer-code process the message one by one sequentially.

Below is my logic that process the incoming message. Having the topic with 4 partitions should the `processEvent` method handle 4 messages in parallel as I run only one instance of this consumer-app. Am I missing anything?

```
@Incoming("topic-1")
@Retry(delay = 3, maxRetries = 3, retryOn = { MyException.class })
@NonBlocking
public CompletionStage<Void> processEvent(KafkaRecordBatch<String, String> payload) {
    Multi.createFrom().iterable(payload.getRecords())
            .onItem().transform(EventProcessor1::newLogEvent).filter(l -> !l.isEmptyEvent())
            .onItem()
            .transform(this::processEvent).onItem().transformToUniAndConcatenate(this::process2).collect().with(Collectors.counting())
            .subscribe().with(c -> {
                log.info("completed {} events", c);
            });

   return payload.ack().whenCompleteAsync((s, e) -> {
        if (e != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        log.debug("batch processed & comitted successfully");
    });
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the number of partitions that should be consumed concurrently. The configuration looks like this:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.my-channel.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.my-channel.xxx=xxx
mp.messaging.incoming.my-channel.partitions=4
```

The `partitions` configuration property defaults to `1`, which is what you see.

See https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.18.0/kafka/receiving-kafka-records/#configuration-reference for details.

Comment: Is the way smallrye implementation of Kafka consumer similar to concurrent consumer provided by the spring-boot?